# How to pipe results of a heavy aggregation to a writable stream? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a heavy aggregation which only works well (even with allowDiskUse: true) if it is limited to 1000 items.

I need to pipe this aggregation to another stream.
However there would be more than 1 page in the results.
At the moment I can only pipe the first page (skip=0, limit=1000) and it works well

Is there any simple way of doing it? `getMore` somehow doesn't seem to work for aggregation cursors?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using mongoose or the native nodejs driver?

Answer (score 0):

Both Mongoose and the native MongoDB NodeJS driver exposes queries as async iterators. The async iterators can be transformed to NodeJS streams using the built-in `Readable.from` on >=12.0, or using a third party library on older versions.

The following snippet is illustrates how to transform a Mongoose aggregation query to a readable stream that can be piped elsewhere.

```js
const { Writable, Readable, pipeline } = require('stream');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

(async ()=>{
    await mongoose.connect( "mongodb://localhost:27017/test" );

    const model = mongoose.model('model', mongoose.Schema({ someProp: String }));

    await model
        .bulkWrite([
            { insertOne: { document: {
                someProp: 'A'
            }}},
            { insertOne: { document: {
                someProp: 'B'
            }}}
        ]);

    // Create an async iterator of the aggregation query
    const aggregationQuery = model.aggregate([]);

    // Transform the async iterator to a stream
    const aggregationStream = Readable.from(aggregationQuery);

    await new Promise( resolve => {
        pipeline(
            aggregationStream, 
            new Writable({
                        objectMode: true,
                        write: (chunk, encoding, next) => {
                            console.log(chunk);
                            next();
                        }
                }),
            resolve
        )
    });

    await model.db.dropDatabase();
    await mongoose.disconnect();
})()
    .catch( console.error );
```

Note that `Readable.from` is not available on nodejs < 12. Older NodeJS versions must transform the iterator using third party code like the [async-iterator-to-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-iterator-to-stream) library:

```js
const asyncIteratorToStream = require('async-iterator-to-stream');

// Transform the async iterator to a stream using the third party library
const aggregationStream = asyncIteratorToStream((
    async function*(){
        for await (const doc of aggregationQuery){
            yield doc
        }
    }
)(), {
    objectMode: true
});
```